# problema com dynamic proxies ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Alguém poderia me explicar um método para não pegar os proxies a partir do DbContext e sim os objetos reais?

Segue um caso:

```
public ActionResult PegarItem(int anuncio, String remetente, int destinatario)
{
     var context = new ReuseContext();
     Anuncio a = context.Anuncios.Find(anuncio);
     Usuario d = context.Usuarios.Find(destinatario);
     if (remetente == null)
     {
         return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
     }
     if (d.Name == User.Identity.Name)
     {
         return RedirectToAction("Index", new { error = 1 });
     }
     Usuario user = context.Usuarios.Where(b => b.email == remetente).FirstOrDefault();
     var mensagem = new Mensagem(a, user, d);
     MensagensController mc = new MensagensController();
     context.Dispose();
     mc.Create(mensagem);
     return RedirectToAction("Index", new { success = 1 });
}
```

Quando é realizado `db.SaveChanges();`, ele cria uma nova entidade para os 2 usuarios e o anúncio, sei que isso ocorre por causa dos proxies, mas não sei como impedir isso em C#.

```
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "MensagemID,DataPostada,Remetente,Destinatario")] Mensagem mensagem)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Mensagems.Add(mensagem);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(mensagem);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, você está usando a tecnologia errado. Por isso tem esses resultados.

Essas duas linhas não fazem o menor sentido:

```
MensagensController mc = new MensagensController();
context.Dispose();
```

Primeiro porque *Controllers* são instanciados pelo *framework*. Segundo porque você está usando um *Controller* como um *Helper* pra não ter o problema da repetição de lógica, só que um *Controller* devolve um `ActionResult`, que faz parte do ciclo de uma requisição, e não de um bloco de lógica, que é o que você está fazendo. Terceiro porque você está usando dois contextos diferentes com lógica encadeada, e o Entity Framework entende que são entidades novas ao invés das já existentes.

Para resolver, isole sua lógica de criação de mensagens em uma classe estática:

```
public static class MensagensHelper 
{
    public static void CriarMensagem(Mensagem mensagem, DbContext contexto)
    {
        contexto.Mensagems.Add(mensagem);
        contexto.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Modifique sua *Action* no *Controller* para o seguinte:

```
public ActionResult PegarItem(int anuncio, String remetente, int destinatario)
{
     using (var context = new ReuseContext()) 
     {
         var a = context.Anuncios.Find(anuncio);
         var d = context.Usuarios.Find(destinatario);

         if (remetente == null)
         {
             return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
         }

         if (d.Name == User.Identity.Name)
         {
             return RedirectToAction("Index", new { error = 1 });
         }

         var user = context.Usuarios.FirstOrDefault(b => b.email == remetente);
         MensagensHelper.CriarMensagem(new Mensagem(a, user, d), context);
         return RedirectToAction("Index", new { success = 1 });
     }
}
```

Comment: agradeço a resposta, agora compreendo mais a diferença de contexto do meu sistema